# Move to next cell in active row with certain cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select the next cell in a range which is based on the currently selected row that has the value " " (every cell contains an equation, some resulting in " " being the resulting cell value). The range runs from column F - Column YW.

I have started with the following code. Right now it correctly identifies the current row, but moves to column YW, every time, not finding blanks in the intermediate.

```
Sub JumpColumns()
    Dim lnRow As Long
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim searchrange As String
    'Dim strAddress As String
    Dim rngFound As Range, rngCell As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("MP_MacroPractice")
    
    lnRow = ActiveCell.Row              'sets row of search to currently active row.
    
    Let searchrange = "F" & lnRow & ":" & "YW" & lnRow        'sets range to search in
    Set rngSearch = Range(searchrange)                        'sets range to search in
    
    strSearch = " "    'sets string to search for
    
    'Attempted loop to identify the next cell with a value of the search term:
    For Each rngCell In rngSearch 
        Set rngFound = rngCell.Find(What:=strSearch)
    Next
    
    rngFound.Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you looping over `rngSearch`? Also `Let` is deprecated, feel free to remove that.

Comment: Shouldn't it loop over the search area? I haven't coded in a few years so super rusty here, sorry. Thanks for the note on let, i'll get that updated.

Comment: No loop: `Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=strSearch)`. You should also specify the `LookIn:=` and `LookAt:=` parameters too.